# Mask in JQuery overlay function dimming main div element also

Tags: jquery, overlay

Doing a JQuery overlay call using this demo: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html

Overlay is showing for me, but the mask in the overlaying is affecting the entire page and not exposing the main div element.  I.E. the popup box is dimmed out and opaque also.

I am pulling the JQuery library and tools with the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="contact_overlay" id="overlay_1">
<div class="close">X</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact_overlay {
display:none;
z-index: 1000;
background-color:#d1e8db;
width:700px;
min-height:350px;
border:1px solid #666; 
-moz-box-shadow:    0 0 90px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 90px #000;
box-shadow:         0 0 90px 5px #000;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-right: 100px;
}
.contact_overlay .close {
position:absolute;
right:3px;
top:3px;
cursor:pointer;
width: 22px;
height: 17px;
-webkit-border-radius: 11px;
-moz-border-radius: 11px;
border-radius: 11px;
border: 0px;
background-color: #959595;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 6px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.easing.drop = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
};
$.tools.overlay.addEffect("drop", function(css, done) {
var conf = this.getConf(),
overlay = this.getOverlay();
if (conf.fixed)  {
    css.position = 'fixed';
} else {
    css.top += $(window).scrollTop();
    css.left += $(window).scrollLeft();
    css.position = 'absolute';
}
overlay.css(css).show();
overlay.animate(
    { top: '+=55',  opacity: 1,  width: '+=20'}, 400, 'drop', done
);
}, function(done) {
this.getOverlay().animate(
    {top:'-=55', opacity:0, width:'-=20'}, 300, 'drop',
    function() {
        $(this).hide();
        done.call();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[rel]").overlay({
    effect: 'drop',
    mask: '#789',
    })
});
```

Example image of the issue:
[image: Issue with Mask]

Comment: is the z-index for the main div (popout div) higher than the overlay?

Comment: Contact_overlay is the "popup" or the green box element in the photo and it has a z-index of 1000.  The highest of all other elements.

Comment: can you make a fiddle, or link to an example site? can't really help much from your code, I don't see how the overlay is generated.

Comment: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/custom-effect.htm

Comment: in the example, the overlay's z-index is set to 9998, meaning your div needs to be 9999

Comment: I input a z-index of 9999 and then 100000000 for the div of contact_overlay - neither didn't dim the element though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to give the popup a higher z-index value than the overlay.

Comment: The `body` had a z-index that was overriding the div element I was calling.  Took a little while to figure out my z-index wasn't being set.